# Сноситься / связаться

Tags: глаголы, этимология

While reading a Russian language resource published in 1950, I noticed that

> сноситься/ снестись

was translated as "to get in contact with."
After reviewing some online dictionaries, I found the same definition, and browsing the internet returned hits like:

> мы неслись по телефону

But I don't think I've ever heard this phrase spoken in conversation. Rather, I hear:

> связываться/связаться

A question for native speakers: has using the first verb gone out of fashion? If so, when did that happen, and if not, in what contexts is it appropriate to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A question for native speakers: has using the first verb gone out of fashion?

Yes, it has.

There is a sharp decline in its use after the 1940s, and the remaining uses seem to be those of the homonyms ("to be demolished", "to lay eggs" etc.)

> After reviewing some online dictionaries I found the same definition, and browsing the internet returned hits like *мы неслись по телефону*

The phrase *мы снеслись по телефону* (sic) is an old-fashioned way to say "we had a phone conversation" (literally, "we got in contact over the phone" or "we connected over the phone").

I found [one use of it](https://news22.ru/2023/03/01/dikaya-istoriya-materi-11-detey-vmesto-zvaniya-geroini-poluchila-odni-unizheniya.html) online, in an article which is clearly written by an AI.

> In what contexts is it appropriate to use?

I believe it has its limited use in officialese in the context of "foreign relations".

The Vienna Convention on Diplomatic Relations (1961) is *Венская конвенция о дипломатических сношениях* in Russian.

For a brief period of time in the early 1990s, the Soviet ministry of the foreign affairs was called *Министерство внешних сношений*.

Nowadays, both "diplomatic relations" and "foreign relations" are much more likely to be *отношения*.